# C# For-Loop not adding Items to Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, observablecollection

SO I'm having an issue with adding values into a observable collection with a for loop. I'm trying to add 625 values to the collection but it skips some values and I've got not clue why or I'm to blind to see the issue...

As seen in the code, I've got two Collections, one that I already prefil with values in the constructor (no problems with that) and another one that I'm trying to fill with new values from ground. I've got a for loop that loops 625 times (works aswell) but somehow some values are skipped and I dont know why.

Maybe also to say I've got an method that changes on click some values inside CellCollection but this happpens before the for loop and actually has nothing to do with it but maybe it's worth mentioning.

Method with the For-Loop:

```
     void neighborCalc()
            {
                //calculates alive neighbors and kills or sets cell alive
                for (int i = 0; i < CellCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    int neighborAliveCounter = 0;

                    //check top
                    if (CellCollection[i].Row > 1)
                    {
                        CellModel topCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row - 1);
                        if (topCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check bottom
                    if (CellCollection[i].Row < 25)
                    {
                        CellModel bottomCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row + 1);
                        if (bottomCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check left
                    if (CellCollection[i].Column > 1)
                    {
                        CellModel leftCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column - 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row);
                        if (leftCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check right
                    if (CellCollection[i].Column < 25)
                    {
                        CellModel rightCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column + 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row);
                        if (rightCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check topleft
                    if (CellCollection[i].Column > 1 && CellCollection[i].Row > 1)
                    {
                        CellModel topLeftCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column - 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row - 1);
                        if (topLeftCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check top right cell
                    if (CellCollection[i].Row > 1 && CellCollection[i].Column < 25)
                    {
                        CellModel topRightCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column + 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row - 1);
                        if (topRightCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check bottom left cell
                    if (CellCollection[i].Row < 25 && CellCollection[i].Column > 1)
                    {
                        CellModel bottomLeftCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column - 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row + 1);
                        if (bottomLeftCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //check bottom right cell
                    if (CellCollection[i].Row < 25 && CellCollection[i].Column < 25)
                    {
                        CellModel bottomRightCell = CellCollection.Single(cell => cell.Column == CellCollection[i].Column + 1 && cell.Row == CellCollection[i].Row + 1);
                        if (bottomRightCell.IsAlive == true)
                        {
                            neighborAliveCounter = neighborAliveCounter + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //decides if to put cell alive or dead
                    if (neighborAliveCounter < 2 || neighborAliveCounter > 3)
                    {
                        tempCollection.Add(new CellModel() { Row = CellCollection[i].Row, Column = CellCollection[i].Column, CellBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), IsAlive = false });
                    }

                    if (neighborAliveCounter == 3)
                    {                        
tempCollection.Add(new CellModel() { Row = CellCollection[i].Row, Column = CellCollection[i].Column, CellBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSeaGreen), IsAlive = true });
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure why I don't have the same amount of values in both of them and some Rows / Columns aren't in the indentic spot (what's logical since the tempCollection somehow doesn't have 625 but less values.)

Comment: You're going to be flagged for asking to debug your code dude ^^. Just to help, how do you observe the differences? In GUI or in code? I mean could it be an update issue or is it really not good in the code? What have you tried to debug this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not handling the case where `neighborAliveCounter == 2` here. This is the reason why you're getting incorrect counts. The block of code below only checks for less than 2, equal to 3 and greater than 3.

```
//decides if to put cell alive or dead
                    if (neighborAliveCounter < 2 || neighborAliveCounter > 3)
                    {
                        tempCollection.Add(new CellModel() { Row = CellCollection[i].Row, Column = CellCollection[i].Column, CellBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), IsAlive = false });
                    }

                    if (neighborAliveCounter == 3)
                    {                        
tempCollection.Add(new CellModel() { Row = CellCollection[i].Row, Column = CellCollection[i].Column, CellBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSeaGreen), IsAlive = true });
                    }
```

Comment: wow I feel so stupid for overseeing this mistake and even making this thread. thanks^^

Comment: @C.User Split that Spaghetti-Monster into testable Functions and you see clearer.